# Android WebDriver unable to enter text in the 2nd Text Box( subsequent elements)

Tags: android, selenium, webdriver

Description/Steps:

Using latest android webdriver (selenium-java-2.28.0.zip ) if the screen is invoked (HTML File attached)using the following code:

#######################################3

```
WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver();
driver.get("http://10.178.147.244:8080/TestConnected");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.id("test")).sendKeys("Test");

Thread.sleep(10000);

WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
ele.sendKeys("Test");
```

#

The text is entered in the first field of the screen but the focus is never moved to the next text box.

In any run the code only acts on any one element on screen .

Even Tried using following:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("test")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);

driver.findElement(By.name("test")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

What is the expected output? What do you see instead?

Script should enter values in all the available text boxes on screen.

Selenium version:selenium-java-2.28.0
OS:Android 2.3
Browser:Android Browser
Browser version:HTC Desire Android Browser

WebPage Code:

```
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mobileAppUI.css"/>




</head>
<body >

 <br/>
 <div id="wholeBody">


   <table align='center' >

    <tr id='mdttagtr'>

        <td width='30%' class="oraLabel"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(LABELS.mdttag)</script></td>
        <td width='70%'>
        <input name='test' class="oraInput" type="text" id="mdttag" />

        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='30%' class="oraLabel" id='userLabel'><script type="text/javascript">document.write(LABELS.userId)</script></td>

        <td width='70%'>
        <input name='username' class="oraInput" type="text" id="username" maxlength="256"/>

        </td>
    </tr>


</table>

 <hr/>
```

Comment: currently I am able to accomplish this using JavaScript Executor in Webdriver. Please let me know if there is a better way of doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find element by name and then use sendKeys method.it worked for me.

Comment: There is same problem arised for safari driver and it was confirmed that it is a webdriver bug for safari driver.I think Android driver is also effected with this bug.I was trying with XPath,it didn't work.But By name ,it worked.You can do workwround like this.Thnks

Answer (score 0):

You have entered wrong id for first input element.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("test")).sendKeys("Test");

//here id mention in your html is "mdttag"
<input name='test' class="oraInput" type="text" id="mdttag" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To enter text into second text field use selector "by name"